# compare the value with li element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the node id and append to the div.I want to check the node id which id in div with the class 'node_id'.  and compare the id with li which is having the class name which is equal to class 'node_id'.I have the parent list with class="flex-active-slider".inside parent list I want to take the value with the class="node_id" and check the list which is having the same value. and increase the width of the img inside it

```
<li class="flex-active-slider">
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>  //compare 233
  <ul>
     <li class="69"><img></li>
     <li class="233"><img></li>  // increase width
     <li class="299"><img></li>
  </ul> 
</li>
```

Comment: This seems pretty straight forward, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.text()` on the `.node_id` element to get the value, then use that value to target the `li` with the class that matches.

```js
var node_id = $('.node_id').text();
$('.'+node_id).find('img').css('width','100px');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="flex-active-slider">
  <div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
  <ul>
     <li class="69"><img></li>
     <li class="233"><img></li>
     <li class="299"><img></li>
  </ul> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data info. should not be saved inside `class` attribute, store the data into `data-*` attribute instead. The `data-*` attributes are used to store custom data private to the page or application.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

In your case, the `node_id` should be store inside `data-node-id` attribute.

To answer your question,

1. Get the target node ID
2. Find the `li` element with the save node ID
3. Reset the previously assigned class (Optional)
4. Alter the class if target found